# HOW TO GROUP ROWS OF A TABLE WITH COLUMN DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a query to display the number of containers that only contain products so the date is less than 01/01/2019 and date is not null..

Example:

my table : tab

| Num_Container | Num_Product | Date_Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 1 | A2 | 01/01/2018 |
| 1 | A3 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | A4 | 01/01/2017 |
| 2 | A5 | 01/01/2018 |
| 2 | A6 | 01/01/2019 |
| 3 | A7 | Null |
| 3 | A8 | 01/01/2019 |
| 3 | A9 | 01/01/2016 |

The expected result is:

| Num_Container |
| --- |
| 2 |

The containers must contain only products less than or equal to the date 01/01/2019 and date is  not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function in `HAVING` which can use reverse logic get counting is 0

```
SELECT Num_Container
FROM tab
GROUP BY Num_Container
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Date_Product > TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') OR Date_Product IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: The `CASE` expression is missing the `THEN` clause and the `END` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this

```
select Num_Container
from yourtable 
group by Num_Container
having max(Date_Product)< DATE'2019-01-01'
```

Comment: @D-Shih correctly spotted! I've updated.

Comment: @razfun corrected the query by removing equal sign from the having clause.